# When using repaint it look like this why?

Tags: java

I just want to create a code generator. when a user draws something and then click generate it will show code that you just draw-figture1. But the problem is I using clearscreen-It's boolean to clean the screen. When I draw something it looks likes figure 2 I don't know why?-figture3 for more detail.

```java
package program;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main work = new Main();
        System.out.println("color = "+work.inprogram.color);
        System.out.println("pen = "+work.inprogram.pen);

    }

}
class Main extends JFrame
{
    Inprogram inprogram;
    Main()
    {
        inprogram=new Inprogram();
        setTitle("Tools");
        setSize(1138,743);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        add(inprogram);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
class Inprogram extends JPanel
{
    DrawSection drawSection;
    String color,pen;
    public Inprogram() {
        setSize(1138,743);
        setLayout(null);
        JLabel tools=new JLabel("Tools");
        tools.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS",Font.PLAIN,40));
        add(tools);
        tools.setBounds(60, 52, 187, 61);

        //Bank's section
        JButton pen=new JButton("Pen");
        pen.setBounds(60,159, 151, 48);
        pen.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS",Font.PLAIN,35));
        pen.setBorderPainted(false);
        pen.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pen.setFocusPainted(false);
        add(pen);
        pen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent g) {
                //Typo here Back
                //pen=xxxx;
            }
        });

        //Nongnai's section
        JButton color=new JButton("Color");
        color.setBounds(60,300, 151, 48);
        color.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS",Font.PLAIN,35));
        color.setBorderPainted(false);
        color.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        color.setFocusPainted(false);
        add(color);
        color.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent g) {
                //Typo here Nongnai
                //color=xxxx;
            }
        });

        //Jacky's Section
        drawSection=new DrawSection();
        drawSection.setBounds(259, 55, 819, 549);
        add(drawSection);


        //Phum's Section
        JButton generate=new JButton("Generate code");
        generate.setBounds(558,613, 268, 68);
        generate.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS",Font.PLAIN,30));
        generate.setBorderPainted(false);
        generate.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        generate.setFocusPainted(false);
        add(generate);
        generate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent g) {

            }
        });


    }

}


class DrawSection extends JPanel
{
    int x,y;
    boolean clearscreen=true;
    public DrawSection() {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setSize(830,575);
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                x=e.getX();
                y=e.getY();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        if(clearscreen)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0,830,575);
            clearscreen=false;
        }
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(x,y,10,10);
    }
}
```

**Figure 1-when does not click anything**
[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 2-when clicked**
[image: Figure 2]

**Figure 3-when clicked**
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: you certainly add components to your drawing canvas - sadly these code parts are not part of your question, so we can only wildy guess...

Comment: Sorry, I already upload the new one. @MartinFrank Frank

Answer (score 0):

there is a mismatch in your components size...

when you create your top container `Inprogram` you set its size to `setSize(830,575);` within tis constructor.

later after creation you set its size to `drawSection.setBounds(259, 55, 819, 549);` and add it into `InProgram`

this discrepancy leads to the strange effects you see...

### Solution:

the most simple way would be to remove the size setting in your `InProgram`:

```
//Jacky's Section
drawSection=new DrawSection();
//drawSection.setBounds(259, 55, 819, 549);
add(drawSection);
```

a better way would be to let the `DrawSection` determine it's size and draw whatever size it is...

```
//constructor
public DrawSection() {
    setBackground(Color.white);
    //setSize(830,575); don't set sizer
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {...});
}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    if(clearscreen)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        //g.fillRect(0, 0,830,575);
        g.fillRect(0, 0,getWidth(),getHeight()); //no more hardcoded size
        clearscreen=false;
    }
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(x,y,10,10);
}
```

Comment: I do the section way that you said
https://i.ibb.co/5kPj8G3/figture4.png

Comment: I think it not about fillrect because of went I commend all it if it looks like this.